# Textbook on formal syntax (and semantics) of programming languages

Tags: formal-languages, programming-languages, syntax-trees

I'd like to learn about formal syntax of programming languages: how do we describe the syntax of a programming language and how it should be parsed? How do we assign formal semantics to a parsed program?
I've looked at textbooks like [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structure_and_Interpretation_of_Computer_Programs), but it is very *practical*. I am looking for something more theoretical: an introduction to specifying programming languages fully formally and assigning a fully formal semantics. Is there such a book?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you will like to book [Concrete Semantics](http://www.concrete-semantics.org/) (which is freely available as a PDF). It defines the syntax and semantics of an imperative programming language using the proof assistant Isabelle/HOL. In later chapters also types are added to the language and several examples of program analysis are shown.

Comment: I took a quick look at it, and it's definitely way closer to what I'm looking for! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The book [Practical Foundations for Programming Languages](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1107150302) might have what you're looking for.

An older version of the book can be read [here](http://profs.sci.univr.it/%7Emerro/files/harper.pdf).

Comment: Oh this might be even closer to what I'm looking for, thanks!